# Python Searching and returning text inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

Okay, I have read many similar questions and tried them out but it's not working for some reason.  I have a file with a bunch of lines that look like this:

Here are some words:

```
"<Hello> (silly girl) that isn't what she want(s)"
```

I am trying to search for text of two or more characters within parentheses.  Many combinations of `re.search` and `group()` returns something, but not exactly what I'm looking for.  The value I want returned and printed in this case is: `"silly girl"`.

Right now I have this:

```
regex = re.compile("\((.+.+)\)")
for line in lines:
   m = re.search(regex, line)  
   if m:
      print(m.group())
```

The above prints:

```
(silly girl) that isn't what she want(s)
```

If I change the group index to `1`, as in `print(m.group(1))`, it prints the same thing just without the first parentheses:

```
silly girl) that isn't what she want(s)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I copied my regex incorrectly.  Let me edit. Maybe that's the difference

Comment: Can parens ever be nested? Like `(silly (little) girl)...`?

Comment: There are no nested parens in the text.  I tried jonrsharpe's answer and it worked! And I learned like 3 new things in that post, "?" for lazy search, {2,} for "two or more", and that regex-testing site. So much thanks to this board!

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are *greedy* by default, so capture from the first `'('` (before `'silly'`) to the last (after `'want(s'`). Instead:

- Make it a *lazy* match with `'?'`;
- Use `'[^()]'` rather than `'.'` to exclude parentheses from the match (thanks to @thg435, and see their comment on the question for a potential drawback);
- Use `'{2,}'` to indicate "two or more", rather than two separate "one or more" `'+'`s; and
- Include a capturing group to exclude the parentheses themselves.

Now you have:

```
regex = re.compile(r"\(([^()]{2,}?)\)")
```

This lets you switch to `findall` to get a list of results:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\(([^()]{2,}?)\)")
>>> s = "<Hello> (silly girl) that isn't what she want(s)"
>>> m = re.findall(regex, s)
>>> m
['silly girl']
```

See a demo of the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/yI2iN6).

Comment: jon is there any site where we can learn effective regular expression or meaterials or online stuff

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ if you follow the link at the bottom of my answer there is an online regex tester which I find very useful for developing and testing.

Comment: what is the point of using compile instead of just using findall?

Comment: This expr will have problems with strings like `"(silly girl) want(s) more (stuff)"`.

Comment: @thg435 that's true - any ideas to guard against that case?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'd suggest `[^()]` instead of just `.`. But see my comment to the question.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it may not give any benefits in this case (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile)), but I stuck with what the OP already had.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I was just wondering as I imagine it would actually be slower using compile in this case.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `re.findall(x,...)` is defined as `re.compile(x).findall(...)`, so it's just the same.

Comment: @thg435 I still don't see how they are the same, in your logic `re.findall` uses `re.compile` so how is using `re.compile` and passing that to `findall` the same as just using `re.findall`?